# Change language in the app programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android)

I want to change language in my `SettingsActivity.java` for all Activities immediately.
And save this choice (even when I exit from app or reboot phone) regardless of system locale. 
How can I do that?

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) { 
        switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext()
                    .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;

        case 1: 
            Locale locale2 = new Locale("de");
            Locale.setDefault(locale2);
            Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
            config2.locale = locale2;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext()
                    .getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
            break;          
        }       
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? Language not changed?

Comment: changes not to be applied immediately

Comment: Runtime switching of the language in Android is not supported by default, hence on every configuration change you will have to reset the locale manually. cfr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android

Answer (score 2):

1) between exit app and reboot you can save choice like this:
Create Application class

```
public class MutawaApplication extends Application {
```

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
register it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

In this class in onCreate read language from SharedPreferences. Save it to SharedPreferences when you change lang in app.

2) in your Activities check locale on onResume and if need make `replaceContentView()`